# Provider doesn't update class data

Tags: flutter, dart

`P` is an class to save user information.

```
class P extends ChangeNotifier(){
    String? username;
    void upd(String str){
        userName = str;
        notifyListener();
    }
}
```

Updating data by doing;

```
context.read<P>().upd("Hi");
```

However, the next code returns only `null`

```
context.read<P>().username;
```

`main()` was called with `MultiProvider`.

```
runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ListenableProvider(create: (context) => P()),
         ........
```

Why `username` isn't updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@user18309290](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18309290/user18309290) said, just complementing with a more complete code.

If you want to, you can try it on https://dartpad.dev/ (Just push the FloatingActionButton once at least.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(
  MultiProvider(
    providers: [ListenableProvider(create: (_) => P())],
    child: MyApp(),
  )
);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Test',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter Test'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(context.watch<P>().userName ?? 'Null username'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (context.read<P>().userName != 'Teste 1') {
            context.read<P>().upd('Teste 1');
          } else {
            context.read<P>().upd('Teste 2');
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class P extends ChangeNotifier {
    String? userName;
    void upd(String str){
        userName = str;
        notifyListeners();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `context.watch<T>()`, which makes the widget listen to changes on `T`.